# Git problem when try to discard changes

Tags: git, git-checkout

I do git status:

```
# modified:   xxx/yyy/something.PNG
# modified:   xxx/yyy/something-l.PNG
```

then git checkout xxx/yyy/something.PNG and xxx/yyy/something-1.PNG
but when i do git status again it shows again:

```
# modified:   xxx/yyy/something.PNG
# modified:   xxx/yyy/something-l.PNG
```

Im using Snow Leophard

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I deleted `.git` subfolder on `/xxx/yyy/` and everything is ok now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that you've clipped the output of git status. Those modified files were in the "changes to be committed" section. They're in the index (staging area); that is, you probably at some point ran `git add xxx/yyy/something.PNG` or maybe just `git add .` or `git add -u`.

`git checkout <path>` checks out the version of the given path from the index, not from the current commit. If you want to get back to the version from the current commit, use:

```
git checkout HEAD xxx/yyy/something.PNG
```

`HEAD` refers to the current commit.

Comment: @DaniG: Then, to save us from guessing, could you please paste the *full* output of `git status`? Did `git checkout HEAD <path>` print anything? Did it return success or failure?

Comment: That's more or less the same approach as mine.

Comment: @Korator: Except with more explanation and a single command instead of two (one of which you left implicit), yes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already staged your changes. `git diff` shows nothing while `git diff --staged`  shows that you've changed the files.

In that case, you'll have to unstage them using `git reset HEAD xxx/yyy/something.PNG xxx/yyy/something-l.PNG`.

Otherwise another program may change the files.

**EDIT:**
According to your comment below, the file mode of the files is `755`. So it seems like Windows touched them. Try `chmod 644 xxx/yyy/something.PNG`.

Comment: git diff --staged shows nothing. git diff shows: diff --git a/xxx/yyy/something.PNG b/xxx/yyy/something.PNG index ec24047..1b1f3be 100755 Bynary files a/xxx/yyy/something.PNG b/xxx/yyy/something.PNG differ and something similar to second file.

Comment: The file mode seems a bit like Windows touched them. Try `chmod 644 xxx/yyy/something.PNG`.